# Передача двумерного массива в качестве аргумента процедуры

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

Не понимаю в чём ошибка... Гуглил кучу сайтов, там такой же принцип объявления, но у них нормально всё, а у меня нет.

[image: Ошибка]

```
void CreateRandomMatr(int M[][], int n)
{
    srand(time(NULL));      
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j=0; j<n; j++)
            M[i][j] = rand() % 100;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть несколько вариантов :

1. Указать размер внутреннего и внешнего массивов явно :

   ```
   const int N = 10;
   void CreateRandomMatr(int M[N][N], int n);
   ```
2. Указать размеры только внутреннего массива :

   ```
   const int N = 10;
   void CreateRandomMatr(int M[][N], int n);
   ```
3. Послать массив как динамический :

   ```
   void CreateRandomMatr(int** M, int n);
   // Ну или эквивалентная запись 
   void CreateRandomMatr(int* M[], int n);
   ```